# I couldn't write context.Forward within my async method in my bot application

Tags: c#, botframework

I create a bot application using `C#`.

I want to design my bot using multiple dialogs. In `RootDialog.cs`, I have written code to navigate different dialogs according to the user's input.

I am using `context.Forward` for navigating to next dialog. But it is showing error when using it.Here I have attached my `RootDialog.cs`.

Can anyone help me in solving the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System.Threading;

namespace WebService.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

       public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var message = await result;
            if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("name")) {
            await context.Forward(new NameDialog(), this.DetailDialog);
                context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
            }

            // calculate something for us to return


            // return our reply to the user

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        private async Task DetailDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var message = await result;
            if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("price"))
            {

             context.Forward(new PriceDialog(), this.QuantityDialog, message, CancellationToken.None);
                context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);

            }
        }
            private async Task QuantityDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result) {
            var mess = await result;
            if (mess.Text.ToLower().Contains("Discount"))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("50% discount per each");

            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are facing? `await context.Forward(new NameDialog(), this.DetailDialog);
                context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
            }` This lines seem wrong.

Comment: The error is to call a child dialog and add it to the top of the stack showed in "context.Forward(new PriceDialog(), this.QuantityDialog, message, CancellationToken.None)" line.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `StartAsync()` and `MessageRecievedAsync()` method of the `NameDialog()` and try to check if the IMessageActivity `message` that you are sending as the 3rd parameter to the `context.Forward()` is being sent to the child dialog or not

Answer (score 1):

> The error is to call a child dialog and add it to the top of the stack showed in "context.Forward(new PriceDialog(), this.QuantityDialog, message, CancellationToken.None)" line.

The `context.Forward` is a task like this:

```cs
Task Forward<R, T>(IDialog<R> child, ResumeAfter<R> resume, T item, CancellationToken token);
```

The first parameter `child` means the child **dialog** you want to call, not a task. The second one indicates the method to resume when the child dialog has completed, this method can be implemented inside of the parent dialog. The `item` parameter should be the message you want to send to the child dialog. And the last one is the cancellation token. And type parameter `R` represents the type of result expected from the child dialog and in the meanwhile `T` represents the type of the item sent to child dialog.

So basically, you should be able to call this `Forward` task exactly according to  its constructor. Your code `await context.Forward(new NameDialog(), this.DetailDialog);` is not right. You may try to modify it like this:

```
context.Forward(new NameDialog(), this.QuantityDialog, message, CancellationToken.None);
```

By the way, if you want to call your task `DetailDialog` inside of `MessageReceivedAsync`, you can directly call it like this:

```
await DetailDialog(context, result);
```

For more information, you can refer to [Invoke the 'New Order' dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-manage-conversation-flow#invoke-the-new-order-dialog).

Comment: I tried context.Forward(new NameDialog(), this.QuantityDialog, message, CancellationToken.None). but still it shows error.

Comment: same error in same line (context.Forward(new NameDialog(), this.QuantityDialog, message, CancellationToken.None). the error is to call child dialog and add it to top of the stack.

Comment: @yaduska, maybe there's something wrong with your `NameDialog`, you may refer to this official [Multi-Dialog Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs).

Comment: ~ private async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context) {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
         private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result) {
            var output = await result;
            if(output.Text.ToLower().Contains("Name of the apparelcompanies"))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("A,B,C");
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);;~        This is my NameDialog.cs

Comment: @yaduska, try to change the `IMessageActivity` in your code `private async Task QuantityDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)` to `object`, and the code inside this task should also be modified.

Comment: If I use the object instead of IMessageActivity, Then I can't check user input(message.Text.contains(" ")) and direct to the relevant dialog.

Comment: @yaduska, you can convert the object to `IMessageActivity` firstly like this: `var mess = await result as IMessageActivity;`. If you find this answer helpful, could you please mark this answer?

Comment: I tried. But still it's showing same error in context.forward line.